# Why is Crontab not starting my tcpdump bash script capture?

Tags: linux, bash, cron, tcpdump

I have created a simple bash script to start capturing traffic from all interfaces I have in my Linux machine (ubuntu 22), but this script should stop capturing traffic 2 hours after the machine has reboot. Below is my bash script

```
#!/bin/bash
cd /home/user/
tcpdump -U -i any -s 65535 -w output.pcap &

pid=$(ps -e | pgrep tcpdump)
echo $pid
sleep 7200
kill -2 $pid
```

The script works fine if I run it, but I need to have it running after every reboot.

Whenever I run the script, it works without problem

```
user@linux:~$ sudo ./startup.sh
[sudo] password for user:
tcpdump: data link type LINUX_SLL2
tcpdump: listening on any, link-type LINUX_SLL2 (Linux cooked v2), snapshot length 65535 bytes
1202
35 packets captured
35 packets received by filter
0 packets dropped by kernel
```

but when I set it in the crontab as

```
@reboot /home/user/startup.sh
```

it does not start at reboot. I used ps -e | pgrep tcpdump to make sure if the script is running but there is not an output, it seems that it is not starting the script after the reboot. I don't know if I need to have root permissions for that. Also, I checked the file permission, and it has

```
-rwxrwxr-x 1 user user 142 Nov 4 10:11 startup.sh
```

Any suggestion on why it is not starting the script at the reboot?

Comment: Anything from cron log `sudo cat /var/log/syslog |grep -w 'cron'` (or /var/log/cron).

Comment: FYI you can use `$!` to get the PID of the background job, you don't need to get it from `ps`.

Comment: You have an extra `"` at the end of the crontab line. Is that in the real file or a copying error? If it's real, that would prevent running your script.

Comment: @Barmar Sorry that was a typo. It does not have " at the end. I will check it with $!. Thanks!

Comment: @Gardener, this is what I have from syslog `Nov  4 13:43:15 linux cron[769]: (CRON) INFO (pidfile fd = 3)
Nov  4 13:43:15 linux cron[769]: (CRON) INFO (Running @reboot jobs)
Nov  4 13:51:07 linux cron[768]: (CRON) INFO (pidfile fd = 3)
Nov  4 13:51:07 linux cron[768]: (CRON) INFO (Running @reboot jobs)
Nov  4 13:59:10 linux cron[769]: (CRON) INFO (pidfile fd = 3)
Nov  4 13:59:10 linux cron[769]: (CRON) INFO (Running @reboot jobs)`

Comment: What user's crontab did you put it in? By default only root has permission to run `tcpdump`.

Comment: @Barmar, you got it! Even when the user I am using has root permission, I needed to go by sudo and modify the crontab to run the script after a reboot. Thanks. This resolve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Suggesting to update your script:

```
#!/bin/bash
source /home/user/.bash_profile
cd /home/user/
tcpdump -U -i any -s 65535 -w output.pcap &

pid=$(pgrep -f tcpdump)
echo $pid
sleep 7200
kill -2 $pid
```

Suggesting to inspect `crontab` execution log in `/var/log/cron`

Comment: Thank you for the advice Dudi, I will update the script, but I found a solution using sudo and modify crontab at @reboot to start the script at the start up.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here was that even though the user has root permission, if an script needs to be run in crontab at @reboot, crontab needs to be modified by root. That was the only way I found to run the script. As long as I am running tcpdump, this will require root permission but crontab will not start it at the boot up if it is not modified by sudo.

Comment: It's not that "crontab has to be modified by root", it's that every user has their own crontab. Login as root and then edit the crontab.

Comment: Correct. I thought that my user could execute a script at every reboot, but it does not, even when it has root privileges.